# How to access to memory block which allocated by std::vector?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, memory-management

Many people recommend vector class for variable length array. And I have to pass pointer to memory block to GL. How can I access pointer to memory block allocated by `std::vector`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the address of first element. If your vector is `v` then `&v[0]` will work.

Comment: Isn't this a bad thing to do? Can someone with a better understanding of things than me clarify this point, please?

Comment: @batbrat: no, it's not a bad thing to do, I don't think there are any OpenGL calls that would try to reallocate the block, just read and write the contents. You have to pass the correct length to GL as well.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Thanks for clarifying. I'm glad to know that I can use it safely.

Comment: Be careful with VS in debug mode, if your array is currently empty the debugger will complain if you do `&v[0]`.

Comment: It is not only VS, using &v[0] is only allowed if there actually **is** av v[0] object!

Comment: One caveat: It is generally a bad idea to pass pointers to a container's raw data to some library code when you don't know what they do. In the case of OpenGL, you are lucky, because you know exactly what it does, e.g. glBufferData or glTexImage* will pull a copy before the function call returns, so it is 100% safe. However, if you use client (non-buffer) vertex arrays, OpenGL will do nothing if you specify the vertex pointer, it will pull the data only when you call glDraw[Arrays|Elements]. If that call only happens to be after you've added more data to the vector, the data is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

```
ContainerType* pData  = &vec.front();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> v(1000);

int *p = &v[0];

//treat p as if it points to an array of 1000 ints
//all 1000 ints default-initialized with 0!
```